Inwards Spinning Torus on GPU tensors
I'm struggling to understanding my own code. Could someone help me understand what happened?
with this Y array:
y = np.array([
    [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 0.5], 
    [0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9, 0.5], 
    [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5], 
    [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 0.5], 
    [0.0, 0.9, 0.1, 0.8, 0.0, 0.5],
    [0.9, 0.0, 0.6, 0.9, 0.0, 0.5]
])

and these X inputs:
temperature = np.array([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.7, 1.0])
humidity = np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.6, 1.0])
precipitation = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 1.0])
wind_speed = np.array([0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.5, 1.0])
solar_radiation = np.array([0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])
pressure = np.array([0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 1.0])

I got this output running the code on sequence, right now on this moment
[[0 2 3 4 5 1]
 [1 2 3 4 5 0]
 [1 2 3 4 5 0]
 [1 2 3 4 5 0]
 [1 2 3 5 4 0]
 [1 2 3 4 5 0]]

[[2 4 1 5 0 3]
 [3 1 2 4 5 0]
 [3 1 2 4 5 0]
 [3 1 2 4 5 0]
 [3 1 4 5 2 0]
 [1 2 4 5 0 3]]


[[5 3 0 2 1 4]
 [1 5 0 3 2 4]
 [4 1 5 0 2 3]
 [1 5 0 3 2 4]
 [0 1 4 5 3 2]
 [1 5 0 4 2 3]]

[[1 2 3 4 5 0]
 [1 2 3 5 4 0]
 [1 2 3 5 4 0]
 [1 2 3 5 4 0]
 [1 2 3 4 5 0]
 [1 2 3 5 4 0]]

But today evening, after running the code several times, i got a very different output. They were all the same, every time I run the code, even if i changed the X and Y. It was like the last output print, but with all columns equally.
I doubt this is not normal. But i'm asking here, because i could not understand what was happening today.
And this was the code i was running:

def custom_output_layer(self, inputs, depth=0):
        if depth >= self.max_depth:
            return tf.zeros_like(inputs[:, :self.y_shape])  # Change here to match the output size

        u, v, w, r, s, a = inputs[:, 0], inputs[:, 1], inputs[:, 2], inputs[:, 3], inputs[:, 4], inputs[:, 5]
        c = 1.0  # Assuming c is 1.0
        epsilon = 1e-9  # Small constant to prevent division by zero

        # First part of the formula
        term1_numerator = v + (u - v) / (1 - (u * v) / (c ** 2))
        term1_denominator = 1 + (v * (u * v) / (1 - (u * v) / (c ** 2))) / (c ** 2)
        term1 = term1_numerator / (term1_denominator + epsilon)  # Avoid division by zero

        # Second part of the formula
        term2_numerator = 4 * w * r
        term2_denominator = np.pi * tf.sqrt(1 - (w * r) ** 2 / (c ** 2))
        term2 = term2_numerator / (term2_denominator + epsilon)  # Avoid division by zero

        # Apply the inverse limit of "a"
        term_limit = tf.pow(a + epsilon, -1)  # Add epsilon to prevent division by zero

        result = tf.pow((term1 + term2) * term_limit, self.t)  # Use the generic t

        # Recursive call to further bifurcate the space
        new_inputs = tf.stack([u, v, w, r, s, a], axis=1)
        recursive_result = self.custom_output_layer(new_inputs, depth + 1)

        # Ensure the recursive result has the correct shape with modular adjustments
        recursive_result = tf.concat([
            tf.expand_dims(self.mod(recursive_result[:, 0] + a, 1.0), axis=1),
            tf.expand_dims(self.mod(recursive_result[:, 1] + s, 1.0), axis=1),
            tf.expand_dims(self.mod(recursive_result[:, 2] + r, 1.0), axis=1),
            tf.expand_dims(self.mod(recursive_result[:, 3] + w, 1.0), axis=1),
            tf.expand_dims(self.mod(recursive_result[:, 4] + v, 1.0), axis=1),
            tf.expand_dims(self.mod(recursive_result[:, 5] + u, 1.0), axis=1)
        ], axis=1)

        # Combine current result with recursive result
        combined_result = self.mod(result + recursive_result[:, 0], 1.0)

        # Assume the output coordinates (x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) are based on the combined result
        x1 = combined_result + a
        y1 = self.mod(combined_result + s, 1.0)
        z1 = self.mod(combined_result + r, 1.0)
        x2 = self.mod(combined_result + w, 1.0)
        y2 = self.mod(combined_result + v, 1.0)
        z2 = self.mod(combined_result + u, 1.0)

        return tf.stack([x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2], axis=1)

    def create_model(self):
        input_layer = Input(shape=(self.num_features,))  # Six inputs: u, v, w, r, s, a
        hidden_layer = Dense(self.units, activation=self.activation)(input_layer)
        hidden_layer = Dense(self.units, activation=self.activation)(hidden_layer)
        output_layer = Lambda(lambda x: self.custom_output_layer(x), output_shape=(self.y_shape,))(hidden_layer)

        model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
        model.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss=self.loss)
        return model

I was trying to make an accelerated inwards spinning torus on my GPU and got an output answer. But i didn't expect to find this weirdness.
This was the function that i used to run the code:
def apply_grsba(inputs, y, t=1.0):
    processed_inputs = [input_data ** t for input_data in inputs]
    processed_inputs = np.array(processed_inputs).T
    
    num_features = processed_inputs.shape[1]
    num_samples = processed_inputs.shape[0]
    
    if y.shape[0] != num_samples:
        raise ValueError(f"Shape mismatch: y should have {num_samples} rows but has {y.shape[0]}")
    
    model = gr.GRSBA(num_features=num_features, y=y, t=1.0)
    model.train(processed_inputs, y)
    
    result = model.predict(processed_inputs)
    return result

